# android command-line

Tags: android, command-line

How can I specify command-line parameters when I launch an Android application?

1. With Eclipse
2. Directly from the phone

Answer (score 2):

You can't for all runs of an application.  Most Android phones have no CLI and applications are launched by clicking their icon.

You may able to do this via `adb shell` but this not something your users can do.

What is it that you're trying to do precisely?

Comment: I need to change the stack size with the -Xss parameter